# After downloading the .iso file, what do I do?

Tags: installation, dual-boot

I'm trying to download Ubuntu to be run alongside my current windows 8 platform . I downloaded the 64-bit version. What do I do now? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!

It's very simple actually, just follow this guide [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto). That'll tell you how to burn it to a disk.

As for creating a LiveUSB look [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick)

Because of the fact the you are installing Ubuntu on a Win8 computer, there are a few things you have to do before the install because of some of the new Win8 features like EUFI and SecureBoot. Read this [Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported) question for some help on that.

Best of Luck!

Comment: This helped but I have got stuck on something else and couldn't complete it.